# What's the difference between use and :use in the ns macro

Tags: clojure

What's the difference between `use` and `:use` in the `ns` macro?

[Docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/use) says the following:

```
Use :use in the ns macro in preference to calling this directly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing.

In the `ns` form, you want to use the keyword version `(:require ...)` like:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
```

You should consider this the "normal" way of doing things.

The other version, without the colon, is a ***function*** of the same name that can be called at the REPL in case you can't or don't want to use the `ns` form.  This would look like:

```
> lein repl
user=> (require '[tupelo.core :as t] )
nil
user=> (t/append [1 2 3] 4)
[1 2 3 4]
```

***Please note:*** For the repl/function version, you must also quote the vector containing the namespace specs. Notice that we did not quote the spec in the `ns` version using `:require`.

As an alternative, if you are already in the editor and just want to test something quick at the REPL, you can cut/paste the whole `ns` form from the top of your file into the REPL:

```
> lein repl
user=> (ns clj.core
  #_=>   (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
user=>
```

which is easier and less error-prone than typing the function-version by hand.

For a good overview please see the recent blog posting here:  https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/mIlKaOiujlo).

Comment: Just to be clear:  It's perfectly acceptable to use the function forms `(use ...)` and `(require ...)` from the REPL.  In fact, it's probably preferred in that situation.  But in your source-code files, you should put all that in the `(ns ...)` form unless it absolutely isn't possible (e.g., cyclic dependencies or something).